# Tomcat постоянно выдает ошибку

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, http-status-code-404

Сначала приложения открываються нормально, через некоторое время выдает ошибку 404, потом через пару дней снова всё нормально, и так по кругу. И так со всеми приложениями.

```
Connected to server
[2017-11-29 04:51:53,399] Artifact SpringSecurity:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
29-Nov-2017 16:51:54.430 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2017-11-29 04:51:54,522] Artifact SpringSecurity:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-11-29 04:51:54,523] Artifact SpringSecurity:war: Deploy took 1 123 milliseconds
29-Nov-2017 16:52:02.947 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Oksana\Desktop\Oksana\Setup\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager]
29-Nov-2017 16:52:03.029 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Oksana\Desktop\Oksana\Setup\Development\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\apache-tomcat-8.5.23\webapps\manager] has finished in [81] ms
```

Мой `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: А половина кода так и должна быть закомментирована?

Comment: это не комментарий